# PresentViewController not presenting the view

Tags: iphone, ios

```
-(void) switchtodetail{
    LocorecoDetailViewController *detail_view_controller = [[LocorecoDetailViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:detail_view_controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Above code doesn't present `detail_view_controller`. More info about `LocorecoDetailViewController`, it is the detail view controller template generated automatically when using Master-Detail application template

So I have a controller called `SearchController` which presents a modal view to add a question. `Searchcontroller` is the one which has `switchtodetail` function. `Switchtodetail` presents a modal controller, to add a question. After the question is added, I need to present a new view controller (detail view controller) So the flow is `SearchController` -> Add Question (Modal) -> after adding back to `Searchcontroller` -> `LocorecoDetailViewcontroller`. Last link is the broken one.

Comment: Check the IB connections in Xib.

Answer (score 3):

If above two does not work, try this :

```
 -(void) switchtodetail{

      LocorecoDetailViewController *detail_view_controller = [[LocorecoDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocorecoDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
      [self presentModalViewController:detail_view_controller animated:YES];

}
```

I usually use this to present view controller.  I think one of these three definitely help you to resolve your problem. All the best!

Comment: None of the answers worked so far. My usecase is to present a view programatically, not through storyboard

Comment: First check whether this method is getting called or not? And let us know that on which event you are calling the function?

Comment: Yes switchtodetail is called and self is a instance of UITableViewController which is a UIViewController.

Comment: So I have a controller called "SearchController" which presents a modal view to add a question. Searchcontroller is the one which has switchtodetail function. 

Switchtodetail presents a modal controller, to add a question. AFter the question is added, I need to present a new view controller (detail view controller)

So the flow is

SearchController -> Add Question (Modal) -> after adding back to Searchcontroller -> LocorecoDetailViewcontroller.

LAst link is the broken one

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
[self presentModalViewController:detail_view_controller animated:YES];
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please specify the nib name which you want to load ,so change the line

```
 LocorecoDetailViewController *detail_view_controller = [[LocorecoDetailViewController alloc] init];
```

to

```
  LocorecoDetailViewController *detail_view_controller = [[LocorecoDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocorecoDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
```

And also remove the completion:nill part from the next code